Marine exploration TV show, UK, 80s-90s, male and female diving team
Trying desperately to remember the name of a TV show I used to watch and love with sis and dad when I was around 6-10 yrs old, so late 80s/early 90s, in the UK, which was I think a weekly documentary series with a husband and wife (?) diving team, marine biologists perhaps? 
I have vivid memories of them diving with rays and watching turtles lay eggs etc and I remember loving it. Google has not provided much except the famous team of Ron and Valerie Taylor who I do not believe were the ones. It's frustrating me, anyone remember something like this? I can hear the voices and picture it so vividly but cannot think of anything more specific clue wise to offer!

That would be too late to be Jaques Cousteau then, I guess

It was a BBC show from 1991 named 'Sea Trek'
Sea Trek was a 5 episode documentary TV series featuring Martha Holmes & Michael deGruy  in which specially-developed technology allows the presenters to talk to each other under water.


could you tell us how you figured out the answer to your question?
